# How to load a session by userid using node.js/express/passport/redis?

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I have an application which uses redis as session storage, passport for authentication, everything on top of express.

When a user logs in, the object stored in cache has a structure similar to this one:

```
{
     cookie : {cookie info, expiration, etc},
     passport : { user : 'userid' }
}
```

My question is: is there a simple way to load that session (or session id) inside the node.js app, by providing only the 'userid' field?  (e.g. `loadSession(userid)`, where `loadSession` returns the session id or the session itself).

A native Passport/Express/Connect-Redis alternative is preferred.

My intention is to invalidate a certain session in a given moment, without requiring the user to make an HTTP request to my app, i.e. without `req.session`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just destroy the cached record?

Comment: Because I don't know yet which record contains the `userid` of the session that I want to delete.. that's what I'm trying to find out

Comment: Is the SID not in the cookie?

Comment: yes, but I'm trying to obtain the `sessionid` without that info. It's like, for example, the user (the owner of the session) has a _master_ with the power to end the user's session, by using only the user's id. In that case, the session can be ended without the user making a request, hence not providing a cookie

Comment: If the `userid` is all you have, you'll need to add `node-redis` module and search for the record with that `userid` — it can't be done with `connect-redis` as that module is quite literally ONLY designed for session handling.

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted to know.  I guess I'll try adding to cache another record, with the specific info (e.g. `userid`->`sessionid`) to retrieve it easily. Could you please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if the `userid` is all you have, you'll need to add `node-redis` module and search for the record with that `userid` — it can't be done with `connect-redis` alone as that module is ONLY designed for session handling.